# Copiar, Filtrar colar vba

Tags: vba

Galera boa tarde, preciso filtrar os dados da coluna B que contenham "Cell 01"
 E excluir os demais dados dessa coluna.( em VBA ) tenho algumas observações a serem feitas no projeto.

1- Preciso copiar a planilha toda e colar em um novo arquivo.

2- Manter as fórmulas existentes nela.

o que posso utilizar?

Segue a imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode iterar as linhas usando uma instrução

```
For cont = Plan.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
'Plan é a referência à planilha; cont é uma variável do tipo long.
'Recomendo fazer em ordem decrescente porque em ordem crescente, quando você
'exclui uma linha o excel remunera todas as seguintes para uma a menos, daí o código
'termina indiretamente pulando a próxima linha.
```

Para testar o conteúdo da coluna 2 e apagar a linha respectiva, pode usar

```
If Plan.Cells(cont, 2).Formula = "Cell 01" Then Plan.Rows(cont).Delete
```

Para copiar a planilha, a instrução é

```
plan.Copy
```

Eu meio que terminei te dando o código quase completo, mas se lembre de que o StackOverflow não é um serviço de criação de código, e sim de tirar dúvidas e pedir esclarecimentos. Por isso, nas próximas perguntas, lembre-se de ter algum código como ponto de partida, do qual você tenha dúvidas.

Comment: Obrigado cesar pela ajuda, e sim deixarei o cod.